# icefaces include argument passing

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have two xhtml-s, one including the other. My problem is that parameter passing is not working for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" >

        <ui:include src="core-classic-layout.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="css-basename" value="core-classic"></ui:param>
            <ui:param name="css-themename" value="blue"></ui:param>
        </ui:include>
    </html>
```

and the other core-classic-layout.xhtml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" >

    <f:view locale="#{system.usedLocale}" >
        <ice:loadBundle
          basename="hu.gap.resources.messages"
          var="msgs"/>

    <head>
        <title>#{msgs['ApplFrmTitle']}</title>

        <ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />

        <ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/core/#{css-basename}-layout.css" />
        <ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/core/#{css-basename}-#{css-themename}.css" />
    </head>
```

My problem is that the browser tries to load 0-layout.css ant 0-0.css files, when I navigate to the first xhtml that includes the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-" is an arithmetic operator, so when you write `css-basename` it is `css minus basename`, it evaluates to 0. Calling the param cssBaseName will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This will implicitly include the layouts anywhere you include core-classic-layout.xhtml.

```
<ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/core/#{css-basename}-layout.css" />
<ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/core/#{css-basename}-#{css-themename}.css" />
```

You can just remove the layouts from core-classic-layout.xhtml if you don't want them loaded.